# Google bookmarks - Unable to edit existing bookmarks and also not able to add new book marks

Tags: bookmarks

I have been using google bookmarks (https://www.google.com.au/bookmarks). But recent days, I am unable to edit or add new book marks... When edit button is clicked it just stays on the same page, no response. Has anyone experienced such issues and how can I make it working

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be happening only when you use Australia version of https://www.google.com.au/bookmarks/ page. Same issue not exist with https://www.google.com/bookmarks/ page.